# Por que o Google Chrome não permite copiar uma referência à função console.log?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Tenho um método que recebe uma referência a uma função e utiliza essa referência para exibir um dado (código abaixo). O problema é que quando utilizo a função `console.log` pelo Google Chrome, ocorre uma exceção, que no caso é a seguinte:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation range_methods.foreach (anonymous function)
```

Já no Mozilla Firefox o script executa sem erros. Por que isso está acontecendo? E como posso modificar o script para executar nos dois navegadores?

**JavaScript:**

```javascript
function Range(from, to) {
    'use strict';
    var range_obj, range_methods = {
        from: from,
        to: to,
        includes: function (x) {
            return this.from <= x && x <= this.to;
        },
        foreach: function (f) {
            var x;
            for (x = Math.ceil(this.from) ; x <= this.to; x += 1) {
                f(x);
            }
        },
        toString: function () {
            return "(" + this.from + "..." + this.to + ")";
        }
    };

    range_obj = Object.create(range_methods);

    return range_obj;
}

var r = new Range(1, 3); // Cria um objeto range
r.includes(2); // => true: 2 está no intervalo
r.foreach(console.log); // Exibe 1 2 3
console.log(r); // Exibe (1...3)
```

[**Código no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y5evq/) (no Google Chrome aperte <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> para visualizar o erro no Console)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

O problema é que o console do Chrome quer que `log` seja chamada no contexto de `console` – ou seja, com `console` como `this` –, mas você está chamando a função sem valor definido para `this`.

Uma solução rápida:

```javascript
var log = console.log.bind(console);
r.foreach(log);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y5evq/1/

---

#### Como assim?

Em JavaScript, o valor de `this` dentro de uma função depende de como ela é chamada. Por exemplo:

```javascript
var obj = {
   fn: function() { console.log(this) }
};
var f = obj.fn;
obj.fn();        // loga obj
f();             // loga null no strict mode, ou o objeto global
                 // este é o caso do seu exemplo
```

A linguagem oferece duas maneiras se forçar um valor de `this`:

1. Invocando a função com [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) ou [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

   ```javascript
   f.call(obj);
   f.apply(obj);
   ```

   (Neste caso ambos os métodos são equivalentes, pois só diferem na maneira como os parâmetros devem ser passados – em sequência para `call`, ou como array para `apply`.)
2. Criando uma função atrelada a um `this` específico, com o método [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) que toda função tem (lembre-se de que funções são objetos em JavaScript):

   ```javascript
   var g = f.bind(obj);
   g();
   ```

   (Nota: `bind` (`Function.prototype.bind`) não é suportada em browsers mais antigos. Tem um *shim* <sup>["estepe"? "substituto"]</sup> disponível na [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).)

O objeto `console` é um *host object*, ou seja, um objeto disponibilizado pelo browser, que não faz parte do núcleo duro da linguagem. Como tal, ele tem direito a certas [regalias](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2), incluindo peculiaridades em cada implementação. No caso do console do Chrome, existe essa exigência de que os métodos precisam ser invocados com `console` como `this`, ou a invocação é considerada ilegal.